# Accessing plugin database table in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to access a plugin's database from `functions.php`. With the code below, there are no errors, but there is no data echoing either. By looking around the web there are so many answers for so many different circumstances and none helped me apply any fixes to this particular code.

```
function show_review_count() {
    global $wpdb;
    $dbtable = 'wpcreviews';
    $pageID = 4745;
    $row = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `$dbtable` WHERE    `page_id`=$pageID AND `status`=1");
    echo $row[0]->total;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing [`$wpdb`'s table prefix](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables):

```
$dbtable = $wpdb->prefix . 'wpcreviews';
```